# RegressionMathFunctions deeplearning4j different answers

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

running the [main program](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/feedforward/regression/RegressionMathFunctions.java) more than once results in *different* values for the cost function.

is this correct?

if so, where is that variation coming from?

thanks

edit: i was doing:

```
RegressionMathFunctions.main(args);
RegressionMathFunctions.main(args);
```

which gives different answers.

running the program from eclipse repeatedly gives the same answer, so it looks reproducible.

Comment: Mabye link to the docs! It would not be surprising to see it's using randomness. This means: for reproducible results, you need to fix the random-seed.

Comment: it uses the seed for random and also when it builds the net so i would expect it to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its correct. This is due to random weight initialization, as initial weights in a neural network are typically randomly initialized in a small range. Thus you get slightly different results each time you train a network.

Comment: it uses the seed for random and also when it builds the net so i would expect it to be reproducible.